# How can I make this work?

Tags: html, css, web

Sorry for being vague in my title, I don't know how to explain this.

I am trying to make the nav bar all the way at the top of the page and have the small text under the image.

My css:

```
.profile {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.profile img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px ridge #fafafa;
}
.nav {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    display: table;
}
.button {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    color: black;
}
.button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.button a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #414345;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="profile">
            <img src="assets/img/profile.png">
            <p>Bobby Morton<br>IT Pro</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="button">
                <a href="#">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="button">
                <a href="#">
                    Services
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="button">
                <a href="#">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="button">
                <a href="#">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

So here's what it looks like when I have the .profile class as display: block..

http://codymorton.us/block/

The text under the image works, but my nav bar is pushed all the way down.

But when I make the profile class inline it does this..

http://codymorton.us/inline/

How can I make it so the nav is at the top and the text under the image is still there?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: you need to segregate your menu and your image/text.  Wrap each in their own div and float them left to each other

Comment: Your title isn't clear -_-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is just put you nab bar in a div wrapper and float it to left and then put your profile img and text to another wrapper and float it left or right wherever you want.

you can just put the nav in a wrapper like:

`<div class="nav-wrap">
    //put your navigation here
    </div>`

And after this put the profile info in another div wrapper and add this `display:block` to both of their wrapper.

And you will get the nav bar on the top